# How to fix drainage near foundation

Tags: foundation, drainage

I am in a new build home that has a walk out basement because of the slope the house was built on. This corner of the house has always worried me and with a new patio added, I want to add something to ensure I don't have a drainage issue at this corner. I plan to bury a pipe and attach it to the downspout to help but I also want to account for water runoff from the slope as well.

Any thoughts of what I can add here to better handle water runoff? I was thinking a small retaining wall but unsure how exactly I would do it.

[image]

Comment: Protip: Questions asking about yard grade should show the _whole yard_, or at least the entire relevant area. It's quite hard to give confident answers about drainage while looking through a tube at this little corner.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, retaining walls don't block water (in case that was your assumption). They allow you to change grade more dramatically than you otherwise would, preventing erosion and providing a better appearance.

That said, you need to change grade. You can simply carve it down so it's level or sloped away from the patio, or you can install a retaining wall *parallel to the fence* for some distance, allowing the grade in the vicinity of the patio to be level or sloped away.

Routing your roof runoff is wise, but that's just part of the solution. It allows your grade to shed water without extra load.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with drainage, it's always best to work from the cheapest/easiest to the hard/expensive, one step at a time until the problem is solved. Here's what I normally do when I first encounter a house with unknown soil hydrology:

1. Extend all downspouts so that the water is taken away from the house.
2. Install french drain in the area sloping into the house.
3. Change the slope to that it is away from the house for at least 10', then discharges into a drain away/downslope from the house. This can be as easy as an afternoon with a shovel, a wheelbarrow and some gravel, or as hard as involving heavy earthmoving equipment.

Answer (score 0):

Start with rain drain.

That setup you have will not work draining water far away from foundation. Use closed drain pipe to extend it.

There is already evidance (mud and wall) on the deck that it does not work as is.

[image: mud]